# How to construct an output which consists an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

lets say I have a sample data like this,

```js
const questions_chklist = 
  { credit_broker_checklist: 
    [ { id: '1', title: 'Are any identified risks to the customer given equal prominence?', question_id: 'wmBHr' } 
    , { id: '2', title: 'Content has been approved by an authorised individual',            question_id: 'sPYvu' } 
    , { id: '3', title: 'Does it clearly name your company or the ?',                       question_id: '64bBL' } 
    ] 
  , test_checklist_checklist: 
    [ { id: '1', title: 'new questionn 1',     question_id: '0VsnL' } 
    , { id: '2', title: 'new question 02',     question_id: 'c9jrW' } 
    , { id: '3', title: 'New question 03',     question_id: 'fbJON' } 
    , { id: '4', title: 'new question 412234', question_id: 'AbcDE' } 
    ] 
  , new_list_checklist: [ ] 
  }
```

Now I am trying to create an object like this,

```js
{ credit_broker_checklist: 
  [ { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: 'wmBHr' } 
  , { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: 'sPYvu' } 
  , { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: '64bBL' } 
  ] 
, test_checklist_checklist: 
  [ { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: '0VsnL' } 
  , { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: 'c9jrW' } 
  , { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: 'fbJON' } 
  , { answer: '', comments: '', question_id: 'AbcDE' } 
  ] 
, new_list_checklist: [ ] 
}
```

Currently , I don't know how to generate an object so I am generating like this,

```js
const questions_chklist = 
  { credit_broker_checklist: 
    [ { id: '1', title: 'Are any identified risks to the customer given equal prominence?', question_id: 'wmBHr' } 
    , { id: '2', title: 'Content has been approved by an authorised individual',            question_id: 'sPYvu' } 
    , { id: '3', title: 'Does it clearly name your company or the ?',                       question_id: '64bBL' } 
    ] 
  , test_checklist_checklist: 
    [ { id: '1', title: 'new questionn 1',     question_id: '0VsnL' } 
    , { id: '2', title: 'new question 02',     question_id: 'c9jrW' } 
    , { id: '3', title: 'New question 03',     question_id: 'fbJON' } 
    , { id: '4', title: 'new question 412234', question_id: 'AbcDE' } 
    ] 
  , new_list_checklist: [ ] 
  } 

let jsonObj = []
for (var key in questions_chklist)
  {
  if (questions_chklist.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
    let option_count = questions_chklist[key].length;
    for (let i = 0; i < option_count; i++)
      {
      let item            = {} 
      item ["answer"]     = "";
      item ["comments"]   = "";
      item["question_id"] = questions_chklist[key][i].question_id
      jsonObj.push(item);
      }
    }
  }

console.log( jsonObj )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Its simply creating an array of several objects,

```
[
  {
    answer: '',
    comments: '',
    question_id: 'wmBHr'
  },
  {
    answer: '',
    comments: '',
    question_id: 'sPYvu'
  },
...
....
```

Comment: Why does `id` `1` get to be the only object with comments in your expected output?

Comment: Well yes! Nowhere do you key the output object to the top level keys like "credit_broker_checklist"

Comment: @JeromeTaylor https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267491/7076153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your jsonObj output to be an object, don't initialize it as an array. What you did was loop through each property's value and push the items in the jsonObj array.

Here's your code a bit adjusted to output what you need, if I understood your issue correctly.

```js
let questions_chklist = {
    "credit_broker_checklist": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Are any identified risks to the customer given equal prominence?",
            "question_id": "wmBHr"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Content has been approved by an authorised individual",
            "question_id": "sPYvu"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Does it clearly name your company or the ?",
            "question_id": "64bBL"
        }],
    "test_checklist_checklist": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "new questionn 1",
            "question_id": "0VsnL"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "new question 02",
            "question_id": "c9jrW"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "New question 03",
            "question_id": "fbJON"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "new question 412234",
            "question_id": "AbcDE"
        }
    ],
    "new_list_checklist": []
}

let jsonObj = {}
for (var key in questions_chklist) {
    if (questions_chklist.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       jsonObj[key] = [];
       let option_count = questions_chklist[key].length;
       for (let i = 0; i < option_count; i++) {
          let item = {} 
          item ["answer"] = "";
          item ["comments"] = "";
          item["question_id"] = questions_chklist[key][i].question_id
          jsonObj[key].push(item);
       }               
   }
}
console.log(jsonObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to retain the `question_id` from the original, and then add empty `answer` and `comment` properties.

You can turn your original object to an array of pairs with `Object.entries`, do the mapping, and then turn that back to an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const questions_chklist = { credit_broker_checklist: [ { id: '1', title: 'Are any identified risks to the customer given equal prominence?', question_id: 'wmBHr' }, { id: '2', title: 'Content has been approved by an authorised individual', question_id: 'sPYvu' } , { id: '3', title: 'Does it clearly name your company or the ?', question_id: '64bBL' } ] , test_checklist_checklist: [ { id: '1', title: 'new questionn 1', question_id: '0VsnL' } , { id: '2', title: 'new question 02', question_id: 'c9jrW' } , { id: '3', title: 'New question 03', question_id: 'fbJON' } , { id: '4', title: 'new question 412234', question_id: 'AbcDE' } ] , new_list_checklist: [ ] } 
  
let result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(questions_chklist).map(([name, questions]) => 
        [name, questions.map(({question_id}) => ({
             answer: "",
             comment: "", 
             question_id
        }))]
    )
);

console.log(result);
```